# Onclick event in InfoWindow object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with onclick event in infowindow .. When I change position of marker on map I would like to show a yes/no question asking if I want to save a new position ...I added two buttons (in two ways) to InfoWindow object (markerInfoWin) and looks like the buttons doesn't invoke 'onclick' event .. I tried invoked alert("Test") but nothing happens ..

```
 function addPhotoMarker(lat, lon)
 {
   //.....
   //.....
   google.maps.event.addListener(photoMarker, 'dragend', function(event){
      //....
      //....
      movedMarkerContent(photoMarker);

    });
 }

function movedMarkerContent(marker)
{
  markerInfoWin.setContent('<div class="content"><div class="image"><img class="image_info" src="' + photoPath + '" alt="tu ma byc obrazek!" />'
       + '</div><b>Wspolrzedne GPS: </b>' + marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(3)+", " + marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(3)
       + '<p>Czy chcesz zapisac nowe informacje o polozeniu ?</p><button name="yesBtn" onclick=positionChanged() > Yes </button>'
       + '<input type="button" id="noBtn" value="No" onclick=alert("Test")/></div>');

  markerInfoWin.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
  markerInfoWin.open(photoMap);
}
```

I created button above google maps and it's ok .. but inside google maps in infowindow it's a problem

Comment: Does your onclick not have to be in quotes? For example:

onclick="alert(\"Test\");"

Comment: `onclick="alert(\'Test\');"`

Comment: I tried `... + '<input type="button" id="noBtn" value="No" onclick="alert(\'Test\');"/></div>'` and it doesn't work :/ also when I just want to add listener to InfoWindow obj. it also doesn't invoke alert() ... `google.maps.event.addListener(markerInfoWin, 'click', function(){
        alert("Klik na infowin");
       });` but on map or marker is working

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/TA2EX/

Comment: my bad InfoWindow doesn't handle 'click' ... but I resolved my problem
`google.maps.event.addListener(markerInfoWin, 'domready', function(){
        document.getElementById('noBtn').onclick = function(){ alert('Testt');};
       
       });`

Comment: Thanks for help especially Dr.Molle